# Taghelpers get overwritten by ViewComponent

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

I have ASP.NET Core application (fka ASP.NET 5, ASP.NET MVC 6). The layout page has the following relevant links:

```
<li><a asp-controller="order">Orders</a></li>
<li><a asp-controller="customer">Customers</a></li>
<li><a asp-controller="whatever">Something Else</a></li>
```

and then (via ViewComponent)

```
<li><a asp-controller="account">Login</a></li>
```

Login.cshtml has the following:

```
<form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login" method="post" role="form">
...
</form>
```

or `<form action="/Account/Login">...</form>` - doesn't make any difference.

The problem is that once I click on Login and get into login screen, the top level links (Orders, Customers, etc.) all turn into "/Account/Login"! Obviously, if I put old-fashioned `href`, they remain unchanged. But the most puzzling part is that if I specify Action explicitly -

```
<li><a asp-controller="order" asp-action="Index">Orders</a></li>
```

Everything works correctly! Is it a bug that I stumbled upon, or is it by design that I don't understand?

Comment: You sure they all turn into **account/login** or they turn to **order/login**, **customer/login** etc? Because when you don't specify the action, it would be taken from the ambient route. Take a look at [`UrlHelper.Action`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Routing/UrlHelper.cs#L43) (which is the way the tag helper generates the link)

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me! Are you using attribute routing? (I wonder if this happens only with attribute routing or also with regular routes)

Comment: no, just the regular routing... I'll try attribute routing and see if it makes the difference

Answer (score 0):

The Anchor tag helper defaults to empty when it's unable to find the specified route, so it probably just defaulted to the current page.

```
<a asp-controller="SomeUnknownController">Link!</a>
```

Will produce

```
<a href="">Link!</a>
```

Since we don't know what's going on in your `Account/Login` action we cannot say for sure this is a bug in the anchor TagHelper. But something is messing with the routing somewhere.

Comment: Of course. Order, Customer, and Whatever are all valid controllers that resolve to valid pages until and unless I click on Login link. Sorry, if it wasn't clear in the original question. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry - missed your second point. Account/Login HttpGet action is nothing more than `return View();`

Comment: Yes, of course, but there may be are other things in your project that are messing with the routes - the `Authorize` annotation, options in the `AddAuthentication` configuration section, or some other filter or middleware that you are using. You need to discard that first, so I'd recommend create a new project and try to replicate the problem.